# Delete sql row using button without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to delete a row from table with delete button with confirmation from user but without page refreshing with help of jQuery ajax.

I know a little about php, html, javascript, jquery, and sql. I dont know how to go about doing this but what i really want to do is to be able to pull data from a sql table (i already know how to do this).

Then display the data with a button next to it (i also already know how to do). When they click the button it will remove the element that hold the visible data and also send a sql statment to delete the row in the database. A very crude code over view.

```
<?php
echo '<p>Data 1: '".$someDataFromDB."'<button id='deleteThisRow'></button></p>;
?>
```

**from this I would like to:**

1. Click the button
2. remove the paragraph element so they users know it was deleted
3. then send an sql statement to delete the row from the sql table

All this without refreshing the page. Is that at all possible?

Comment: Yes. You need to search for ajax.

Comment: you should never "send an sql statement". YOu can send an INSTRUCTION to the server telling it to delete a particular record, but your client app should NOT be dealing with anything at the sql level. Consider someone figuring out your "run sql" query syntax and sending over `http://example.com/dosql.php?sql=drop database databasename()` "oops".

Comment: "send an sql statement" I figured it was unspoken that an sql query would be PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you should only send the id of the entry to a particular page to delete the entry.never the entire sql statement.

```
<button id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delbutton"></button>
```

add this script to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {

            $(".delbutton").click(function() {
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var info = 'id=' + del_id;
                if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this post? This cannot be undone later.")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "delete_entry.php", //URL to the delete php script
                        data : info,
                        success : function() {
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                        opacity : "hide"
                    }, "slow");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
 </script>
```

and last but no the least your delete script

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$id=$_POST['id'];
$delete = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($delete) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Perfect. Had to add onclick="" on the button to get the script to run